# How do I theme a MonoTouch application?

Tags: xamarin.ios, themes

I'm doing an MonoTouch application and I would like to apply a theme. (So I don't have to have go around and apply a custom color and style to each view background and button.)

Is there any easy way to do this? So should I be setting the color manually, and use a helper class to determine which color?

e.g.

```
_myButton.Color = ThemeHelper.GetButtonColor();
```

Comment: AFAIK, iOS doesn't provide any good way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at UIAppearance in iOS 5+.  It allows devs to set styles for UI elements globally as in the following example:

```
UIButton.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

For more info, here's a good blog post: http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Oct-14.html